# Тег <audio> в Safari упорно не хочет работать

Tags: safari

Ребята, перепробовал уже все варианты наверное-

```
<audio controls="" preload="none" autostart="false" onplay="resolution=false" onended="resolution=true"><source type="audio/mpeg" src="/assets/users/js/voice/6de87ff31c500a04ad4970cef0629c61.mp3"></audio>
```

```html
<audio src="/assets/users/js/voice/5ebe5570f40962cdd673a61dc05cb8cc.mp3" 
controls="" preload="none" autostart="false" onplay="resolution=false" 
onended="resolution=true"></audio>
```

и wav и ogg пробовал файлы. все браузеры норм воспроизводят любой вариант а на сафарик плеер отображается но когда жму проигрывать то молчит или пишет ошибка....

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогало указание полного url с указанием схемы:

```
src="https://example.com/assets/users/js/voice/5ebe5570f40962cdd673a61dc05cb8cc.mp3"
```

Comment: <audio src="https://test.gdh.kz/assets/users/js/voice/bcc504390040afd0e846dbdb760226a5.mp3" controls="" preload="none" autostart="false" onplay="resolution=false" type="audio/mpeg" onended="resolution=true"></audio>    не помогло((   жму воспроизветси ошибку не выдает но и звука нет)